# Open Graph and internationalization - alway's in english

Tags: asp.net, internationalization, facebook-opengraph, globalization, resourcebundle

This is my first web site and i manage to make everything work except that.

I use ASP.Net and "Resources" files and then set the CurrentCulture which work's fine.

Now I want to share page of my website on Facebook. So i did use Open Graph tags.

I did try many combination of tags and i did try to rescrape in the Facebook Debugger but without succes. The retrieve description and title are ALWAY'S IN ENGLISH.

```
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
```

I also try to add:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="fr_FR" />
```

Without success. I installed curl and run a "refresh" of facebook cache... still without success.

```
curl -X POST -F "id=http://facteurhumain.ca/facteur/lesNouvelles" -F "scrape=true" -F locale="fr_fr" "https://graph.facebook.com" -s
```

I did also try to put "en_US" and "fr_FR" in lower caps ("en_us", "fr_fr") without any changes.

Any pist of solution?

Thanks!!

Comment: Anyone. Still stuck with this one... :(

Comment: Still not resolved. :( Last chance?